# AsyncTask get String value output and store in mainthread variable

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'd like to get the string value output from `AsyncTask`. And store it into a variable on my main thread. How can I do so?

I tried to do `store = new ReceiveData().execute().get()` however it throws an execution exception error. But anyway, my question is not about the execution exception error. I just need a way to get the string out, please help!

Here is my activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  //MAIN ACTIVITIES (REMOTE)

double multiplier;
int seekbarvalue, finallumens;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT); //On orientation change socket will disconnect...
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.SERVER_IP, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    //================START AFTER DEFAULT ON CREATE=================
    SeekBar seekbarbrightness = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbarbrightness);
    final TextView tblumens, tbvolts, tbamps;

    tblumens = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tblumens);
    seekbarvalue = seekbarbrightness.getProgress();
    multiplier = (double) seekbarvalue / 100;
    finallumens = (int) (multiplier * LoginActivity.enterlumens);
    tblumens.setText(String.valueOf(finallumens) + " Lumens");

    tbvolts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbvolts);
    tbamps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbamps);

    seekbarbrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbarbrightness, int progress, boolean b) {
            if (b == true) {
                seekbarvalue = seekbarbrightness.getProgress();
                multiplier = (double) seekbarvalue / 100;
                finallumens = (int) (multiplier * LoginActivity.enterlumens);
                tblumens.setText(String.valueOf(finallumens) + " Lumens");
                if (LoginActivity.getSocket() != null) {
                    try {
                        LoginActivity.getSocket().getOutputStream().write(String.valueOf(multiplier).getBytes());
                        new ReceiveData().execute();
                        //infinite loop here to keep receiving volts and amperes.
                        //Do a split and assign value to volt and amp
                        //String[] strrecv= store.split("|");
                        //String volts = strrecv[0];
                        //String amps = strrecv[1];
                        //tbvolts.setText("Voltage: " + volts + " V");
                        //tbamps.setText("Amperes:" + amps + " A");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NOT connected To Socket, please disconnect and reconnect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });




}
```

And in my `Asynctask` I am doing this.

```
class ReceiveData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String str;
    protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(LoginActivity.getSocket().getInputStream()));
            str = in.readLine();
            return str;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            String str = "fail";
            return str;
        }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
        //super.onPostExecute(str);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `AsyncTask` is to perform asynchronous task in a separate thread to free the main thread and avoid UX issues. For your purpose, I suggest transferring all of the work inside your try block inside the `AsyncTask` and update the UI after execution.

Something like this

In MainThread

```
new ReceiveData().execute();
```

In AsyncTask

```
class ReceiveData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    String volts;
    String amps;

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(LoginActivity.getSocket().getInputStream()));
            str = in.readLine();
            String[] strrecv= store.split("|");
            volts = strrecv[0];
            amps = strrecv[1];
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            tbvolts.setText("Voltage: " + volts + " V");
            tbamps.setText("Amperes:" + amps + " A");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this only works if your `AsyncTask` is defined inside your Activity. If not, you need to create an interface from the `AsyncTask` and implement it in your activity and activate it `onPostExecute`

Comment: I'm trying your method, however I couldn't change the Text when I run the setText function if I place it inside the onpost execute

Comment: The problem is in your textview variables. They are defined locally in your onCreate function and their instance is destroyed after that. You need to persist them. Define them as a class property instead (field). Also, define your asynctask inside your activity so it can access the textview objects .

Comment: Okay i get what you mean. It works very well now! Thank you so much! :) Never did I thought of doing the string split and text setting in the onpostexecution..

Comment: Glad it helped. :)